# How to remove selected row when datagridview is bound to a List<T>

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to remove selected rows from a `datagridview` and my grid was bound to a `List<T>`. I wrote the code which throwing error called

> Rows cannot be programmatically removed unless the DataGridView is data-bound to an IBindingList that supports change notification and allows deletion

This is my full sample code which I have tried but it is not working.

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        List<person> _person = null;
        private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _person =new List<person>();
            _person.Add(new person { ID = 1, Name = "Tridip" });
            _person.Add(new person { ID = 2, Name = "Sujit" });
            _person.Add(new person { ID = 3, Name = "Arijit" });

            dgLogList.DataSource = _person;
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewRow dvr in dgLogList.SelectedRows)
            {
                if (dvr != null)
                {
                    _person.RemoveAt(dvr.Index);
                    dgLogList.DataSource = _person.ToList();
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public class person
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

So please tell me how could I remove selected rows from a `datagridview` when it is bound to a `List<T>`.

Comment: Since you are using a datasource, manage and manipulate that

Comment: `_person.ToList()`  Don't do this. In fact, comment out that line entirely. Use a BindingList instead of a List to have this work.

Comment: Im trying your code and it works, i cannot reproduce the error, are you actually selecting the full row?

Comment: yes i select full row. how did you select row ?

Comment: You do have one mistake, if you select multiple rows you cant use foreach that way, but im not getting the binding error you are mentioning, are you using a datagridview control? (yes it may seem a little obvious you are but, as im telling you im not getting any error) what framework version are you using?

Comment: For removing multiple rows, you should loop in reverse order so that the index positions don't get messed up.  As mentioned, your posted code does not reproduce that error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of binding the DataGridViewRow to your List, bind it to a BindingSource instance. The BindingSource acts as a intermediary between your Grid and List. Also make sure to call the Refresh() method following your row(s) deletion. Here is your code including the updates.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private BindingSource _source = new BindingSource();
    List<person> _person = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _person = new List<person>();
        _person.Add(new person {ID = 1, Name = "Tridip"});
        _person.Add(new person {ID = 2, Name = "Sujit"});
        _person.Add(new person {ID = 3, Name = "Arijit"});
        _source.DataSource = _person;
        dgLogList.DataSource = _source;

    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow dvr in dgLogList.SelectedRows)
        {
            if (dvr != null)
            {
                dgLogList.Rows.Remove(dvr);
                dgLogList.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class person
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```